# Triangulate a surface given as a MeshRegion

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, mesh

Suppose I have a surface given as a `MeshRegion`.  Example:

```
r = DiscretizeRegion[RegionBoundary@Cuboid[], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

```
{RegionDimension[r], RegionEmbeddingDimension[r]}
(* {2, 3} *)
```

How can I triangulate the faces, or refine an exsiting triangulation, so that each face would look similar to this below?

[image]

I know that I can in principle I can do something like this:

```
MeshRegion[
  RegionBoundary[
   TriangulateMesh@
    DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]],
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}
]
```

But this will triangulate the whole 3D volume.  I was wondering if there is a way that avoids this.  Also, some of the surfaces I have won't easily convert to a `BoundaryMeshRegion` that can be triangulated in 3D (e.g. because the surface may not be closed).

---

An alternative starting point could be triangle-based instead of quadrangle based:

```
r = DiscretizeRegion[RegionBoundary@Cylinder[], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use `DiscretizeRegion` again but with a lower `MaxCellMeasure`?

```
mr = DiscretizeRegion[RegionBoundary[Cuboid[]], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeRegion[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> .01}, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: I really thought I tried that and it didn't work!  Apparently I did something wrong.  This is the useful answer for me because it preserves neighbourhood relations.  Triangulating faces separately doesn't.  If you look carefully at the images in the other answers, the subdivision of the cube edges isn't identical between faces either.  With this method it is.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah yes I see what you are saying. Just as an FYI, you could always add an extra step after triangulating faces separately and fix that issue with `RepairMesh[r2, "TJunctionEdges"]`.

Comment: I didn't even consider this. Feeling a bit foolish now...

Comment: @Szabolcs What version are you on? All 3 of those examples work for me on 11.0.0.

Comment: @ChipHurst I am sorry, I am stupid.  I used `MaxCellMeasure -> number` instead of `MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> number}`. Need more coffee ... won't comment today anymore before thinking things through 3 times.  Yes, everything works correctly.

Comment: @Szabolcs no worries!

Comment: BTW in case you're interested: the whole purpose of this question was to implement [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130234/12) (surfaces smoothening).

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of spelunking I got this:

```
r = DiscretizeRegion[RegionBoundary@Cuboid[], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}];

Needs["TriangleLink`"]

r2 = Region`Mesh`Triangulate3DFaces[r, TriangleTriangulate[#, "pqa0.01"] &]
```

[image]

```
{RegionDimension[r2], RegionEmbeddingDimension[r2]}
(* {2, 3} *)
```

The [TriangleTriangulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/TriangleLink/ref/TriangleTriangulate.html) documentation describes how to control the triangulation.

Answer (score 5):

This is a hack, but it does the trick.  The problem is that you can't use `TriangulateMesh` on a 2D polygon embedded in 3D.  One solution is to translate/rotate your polygon to the xy plane, triangulate, then reverse the transformation.

```
triangulate3DPolygon[Polygon[pts__], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
    {a, b, c, U, V, W, tr, trpgon, newpts, newpgns},
    (*The rotation matrix - http://math.stackexchange.com/a/856705 *)
    {a, b, c} = pts[[;; 3]];
    tr = a;
    {a, b, c} = # - a & /@ {a, b, c};
    {U, W} = {Normalize[b], Normalize[Cross[b, c]]};
    V = Cross[U, W];
    {U, V, W}.(# - tr) & /@ pts;
    trpgon = TriangulateMesh[
        DiscretizeGraphics[
            Polygon[Most /@ ({U, V, W}.(# - tr) & /@ pts)]],
            opts
            ];
    newpts = (Transpose[{U, V, W}].PadRight[#, 3] + tr) & /@  MeshCoordinates[trpgon];
    newpgns = MeshCells[trpgon, 2];
    {newpts, newpgns}
];

Options[triangulate2DMeshEmb3D] = {"OutputType" -> "MeshRegion"};
triangulate2DMeshEmb3D[mesh_,opts : OptionsPattern[
    {MeshRegion, TriangulateMesh, Graphics3D, triangulate2DMeshEmb3D}]
    ] :=Module[ {pgons, data, extracount, bag, pgonPrimitives, head, pts},
    pgons = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
    data = triangulate3DPolygon[#, 
        Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[TriangulateMesh]]] & /@ pgons;

    extracount = 0;
    bag = Internal`Bag[];
    pgonPrimitives = {};

    Do[
     pgonPrimitives = Join[
        pgonPrimitives,
        data[[n, 2]] /. Polygon[a__] :> Polygon[a + extracount]
     ];
     Do[
      extracount++;
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, pt],
      {pt, data[[n, 1]]}
      ];
     , {n, Length@data}
     ];
    head = Switch[OptionValue["OutputType"], "MeshRegion", MeshRegion, 
      "Graphics3D", Graphics3D@*GraphicsComplex];
    pts = Internal`BagPart[bag, All];
    Clear[bag];
    head[pts, pgonPrimitives, 
     Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[head]]]]
];
```

If you don't tell `MeshRegion` to color the lines in black, then you might think it didn't work,

[image]

But you can see that it does work, and the triangulation is customizable,

```
triangulate2DMeshEmb3D[
   msh,
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black},
   MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {.2, .01}
Through[{RegionEmbeddingDimension, RegionDimension}[First@%]]
```

[image]