# Numerical solutions of active 1D wave equations

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity, finite-difference-method

I would like to solve the following PDE with finite difference method. The PDE is from the following paper, (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11823.pdf). I would like to implement the algorithm for the left panel of Figure 3 in this paper.

Below is a brief overview of the computational part of this paper.

$-\frac{\partial ^{2}\Psi}{\partial t^{2}}+\frac{\partial ^2\Psi}{\partial {r^2_*}}-V_s(r_*)\Psi=0. $.......................(1)

For this PDE, let's do the following coordinate transformation first,

$ u=t-r_*, v=t+r_*$.

So we can get,

$ r_*=\frac{v-u}{2}$,

$r_*$ is the tortoise coordinate. It can be calculated as following form,

$ dr_*=\frac{1}{f(r)}dr=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}}dr$

And another function is $V_s(r_*)$, it is the effective potential, and we only know the following form,

$V_s(r)=(1-\frac{2M}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}})(\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2+a^2})$

So $V_s(r_*)$ can be solved by using inverse function.

With the setup above, the equation (1) can be written as

$ 4\frac{\partial ^{2}\psi(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v}=-V_s(r_*)\psi(u,v)$....................  (2)

For this PDE, the appropriate discretization scheme is

$\frac{\partial ^{2}\psi(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v}\to \frac{-\psi(u,h+v)-\psi(h+u,v)+\psi(h+u,h+v)+\psi(u,v)}{h^2}$...............(3)

$h$ is the step of the grid. Then the equation (2) can be written as

$4\frac{(-p(u,h+v)-p(h+u,v)+p(h+u,h+v)+p(u,v))}{h^2}+V_s\left(\frac{v-u}{2}\right) p(u,v)=0$...........(4)

For this equation (4), Its initial conditions we know are

$\psi(0,v)=e^{-\frac{(v-10)^2}{18}},  \psi(u,0)=0$.

And I want to get the time evolution of $\psi$ and $t$.

Like the following picture, the values we used is $M=0.5,a=1.01,l=1$.

[image: plot of possible solution]

And the following is my try using Mathematica, but I failed. I would appreciate it if you could sort it out. And I'll fill you in on any details if you need. Thank you!

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 1/2;
a = 1.01;
rs[r_] = Integrate[1/(1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]), r];
l = 1;
V[r_] = (1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]) (l (l + 1)/(r^2 + a^2));
Vs[r_] = V@InverseFunction[rs][r]; (*$Vs[r_*]$*)

{p[u + h, v + h] == p[u + h, v + h] + O[h]^3, 
  p[u + h, v] == p[u + h, v] + O[h]^3, 
  p[u, v + h] == p[u, v + h] + O[h]^3} // Normal

(* discretization *)
disc = Simplify[
  Solve[Normal[{p[u + h, v + h] == p[u + h, v + h] + O[h]^3, 
     p[u + h, v] == p[u + h, v] + O[h]^3, 
     p[u, v + h] == p[u, v + h] + O[h]^3}], {D[p[u, v], u, v]}, {D[
     p[u, v], u], D[p[u, v], v]}
            ]]


equForm = 4*D[p[u, v], u, v] + Vs[(v - u)/2] p[u, v] == 0 /. disc[[1]]

h = 1/2;
(*PDE Linear algebra*)
ecu[{u_, v_}] = equForm;

(* initial condition *)
p[0, v_] = Exp[-(v - 10)^2/(2*3*3)];
p[u_, 0] = 0;

(* Inside the solution range,the grid is divided *)(* the value of 17 \
in the following maybe is not right*)
coords = Flatten[
   Table[{u, v}, {u, h, 17 - h, h/2}, {v, h, 17 - h, h/2}], 1];

(*PDE turns to Linear algebraic equations made up of many，many \
equations*)
ecus = ecu /@ coords;

(*An unknown quantity in a linear algebraic equation*)
vars = Union[Cases[ecus, p[_, _], \[Infinity]]];

(*Numerical solution of linear algebraic equations*)
sol = NSolve[ecus, vars];

(*I want to get the time evlution of \[Psi] and t, but I don't how to \
do it *)
LogPlot[Abs[p[0, v]], {v, 0, 17}, PlotRange -> All]
```

At the same time, I also share another way to calculate the $\psi$ and $t$ directly. The following is my try.

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 1/2;
a = 1.01;
rs[r_] = Integrate[1/(1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]), r];
l = 1;
V[r_] = (1 - (2 m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]) (l (l + 1)/(r^2 + a^2));
Vs[r_] = V@InverseFunction[rs][r];
Plot[Vs[r], {r, -80, 80}, PlotRange -> All]

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] + Vs[x]*u[t, x] == 
    D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == E^(-((x - 10)^2)/18), 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[t, -250] == 0, u[t, 250] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 500}, {x, -250, 250}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 50, "MinPoints" -> 50, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}](* Method\[Rule]{"ExplicitRungeKutta","StiffnessTest"\
\[Rule]True},MaxSteps\[Rule]1*^5,InterpolationOrder\[Rule]All *)

LogPlot[Abs[sol[t, 10]], {t, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, campared with the figure of the paper, the accuracy of this method is not high. I think it's because the internal approach is not chosen properly. I tried using Runge Kutta method and  the optimized discrete scheme provided by xzczd. This only requires changing the `Method` in `NDSolve`. It was for precision reasons that I chose to use the finite difference method. However, when using a coordinate transformation, the initial conditions will change.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I read your program on finite difference methods.  You're good at the use of Mathematica.  I have met a problem and am still at a standstill. I hope you can read my post in your spare time if possible.  I'll keep you posted.  Thank you! @xzczd

Comment: Liu's, "But I failed" is not specific enough. Can you tell us exactly whether your code fails to run, and with what error, or if it runs but the results are not what you expect, etc? Which step fails exactly? If you pinpoint the problem, you will more easily get help.

Comment: I think I didn't put in boundary conditions and that's what caused the problem.  However, the boundary conditions are not given in the literature.  When I try to add two boundary conditions, the equation is solvable, but it's not what I want.  Also, I want the time evolution of $\psi$and $t$, but I don't know how to convert coordinates.  In the end, the problem may also lie in the division of the grid, which I am not sure is correct.  @MarcoB

Comment: Mathematica has a framework for solving differential equations centered around `NDSolve`. Have you tried that out, instead of rolling your own solver? What led you to avoid the built in?

Comment: @Liuvv Where did you get this model?

Comment: Well, your @ won't work in this case. (As to the usage of @ you may want to read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/284701) Then, I'm in a hurry at the moment so can't go through the code, but 2 issues I can spot: 1. "I think I didn't put in boundary conditions… " No, after the coordinate transform the 2 i.c.s are enough to determine a solution even for FDM. 2. "I want to get the time evlution of `\[Psi]` and `t`… ", you need to transform from the $(u, v)$ coordinates back to the $(t, r_*)$ coordinates. BTW it this your classmate?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/260844/1871

Comment: @MarcoB： I tried to solve it using `NDSolve` with Runge Kutta method directly. It is easy to achieve, but it wasn't accurate enough.  To be precise, the order of magnitude does not reach the situation mentioned in the picture of paper. So, the FDM is necessary for me to study.

Comment: @AlexTrounev:  This is a method mentioned in a paper.

Comment: @xzczd: Thank you very much for your advice. Your tips helped me a lot. I looked at your two questions carefully. This line of thinking is correct and I am ready to solve it. Next, I'll figure out a way to fix it even though it's hard for me at the moment. If you have time, also bother you to help check the cause of the problem. Or apply the program to an equation you're familiar with. Thank you. In addition, the owner of another post is my senior fellow apprentice. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: “I tried to solve it using `NDSolve` with Runge Kutta method directly. ” You should not. The default ODE solver of `NDSolve` is quite robust, and the options for adjusting ODE solver should always be the last thing to touch. If the result isn't desired, try adjusting the options for spatial discretization first, here is an example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/196898/1871 "This is a method mentioned in a paper. " It's better to add the link of the paper to the question if it's convenient for you.

Comment: You should add these new info into the body of the question by clicking the [Edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/261065/edit) button.

Comment: As already noted by xzczd, please [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/261065/edit) to include a link to the paper you are studying.

Comment: @xzczd: and J. M. can't deal with it♦ Thank you for your warm introduction.  I have updated some of the details of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: "FiniteElement" works too: `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"(*,
    "MeshOptions"\[Rule]{"MaxCellMeasure"\[Rule]0.3}*)}`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Thank you for your suggestion. It can be calculated inthis way, but it's not as accurate as it is in this paper.  Thank you!

Comment: @Nasser: Sorry to bother you. I know you recently looked at a programming problem about the wave equation. My question is similar to his. If you are in your free time, I would like to ask you for help to look at my question? Thank you!

Comment: @Stone Where is the second part of your question???

Comment: Please don't remove useful info from the question.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your advice and help. However, in order not to cause unnecessary trouble, I still decided to remove the link to the paper, please you can understand. The key information has been recorded in the document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem can be solved with method of lines and with FDM as well. Using `NDSolve` we have

```
m = 1/2; int = 
 Integrate[1/(1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]), r, Assumptions -> a > 0];
rs[x_] := int /. r -> x;
a = 1.01;
l = 1;
r[x_] := InverseFunction[rs][x];
V[r_] := (1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]) (l (l + 1)/(r^2 + a^2));
Vs[x_] := V@InverseFunction[rs][x];
```

We can compare different definitions of potential

```
{Plot[r[x], {x, 0, 40}], Plot[rs[x], {x, 0, 10}], 
 Plot[V[r[x]], {x, 0, 30}], Plot[Vs[x], {x, 0, 30}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

There are several options for method of lines to solve this problem. First variant is similar to FDM

```
eqs = {4*D[p[u, v], u, v] + Vs[(v - u)/2] p[u, v] == 0, 
   p[0, v] == Exp[-(v - 10)^2/(2*3*3)] Tanh[3 v], p[u, 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, p, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 1200, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]
```

Visualization in large and small scale

```
{LogPlot[Abs[sol[t - 37, t + 37]], {t, 37, 400 - 37}], 
 DensityPlot[Abs[sol[u, v]], {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[Abs[sol[u, v]], {u, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Second variant has high difference order, and less points

```
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, p, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 400, "MaxPoints" -> 800, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 8}}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Third variant has same points as first one, but more high difference order

```
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, p, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 400, "MaxPoints" -> 1200, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Practically we have same pictures in 3 different options. To speedup computation we can use interpolation for inverse function as suggested by xzczd in the form

```
Va = FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate[Vs[x]], {x, -400, 400}] // Quiet

eqs = {4*D[p[u, v], u, v] + Va[(v - u)/2] p[u, v] == 0, 
   p[0, v] == Exp[-(v - 10)^2/(2*3*3)] Tanh[3 v], p[u, 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, p, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 400, "MaxPoints" -> 1200, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes 4 second only.
Now we can test FDM. We use algorithm described in the paper cited as follows

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 1/2; int = 
 Integrate[1/(1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]), r, Assumptions -> a > 0];
rs[x_] := int /. r -> x;
a = 1.01;
l = 1;
r[x_] := InverseFunction[rs][x];
V[r_] := (1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]) (l (l + 1)/(r^2 + a^2));
Vs[x_] := V@InverseFunction[rs][x];
L = 100; Va = 
 FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate[Vs[x]], {x, -L, L}] // Quiet;
n = 1000; P = Array[p, {n, n}];
h = L/(n - 1); h2 = 1/8 h^2; eq = 
 Table[-P[[i + 1, j + 1]] + P[[i + 1, j]] + P[[i, j + 1]] - 
    P[[i, j]] - 
    h2 (Va[h (j - i - 1)/2] P[[i + 1, j]] + 
       Va[h (j - i + 1)/2] P[[i, j + 1]]) == 0, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, 
   n - 1}]; bc = 
 Join[Table[P[[1, j]] == Exp[-(h (j - 1) - 10)^2/(2*3*3)], {j, n}], 
  Table[P[[i, 1]] == 0, {i, 2, n}]];
eqs = Join[Flatten[eq], bc];
var = Flatten[Table[P[[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}]];
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, var];

sol = LinearSolve[m, -b];
sol1 = Transpose[Partition[sol, n]];
```

We can compare FDM solution with `NDSolve`

```
eqs = {4*D[psi[u, v], u, v] + Va[(v - u)/2] psi[u, v] == 0, 
   psi[0, v] == Exp[-(v - 10)^2/(2*3*3)] Tanh[3 v], psi[u, 0] == 0};
sol2 = NDSolveValue[eqs, psi, {u, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 1000, "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]
```

Visualization

```
{ArrayPlot[Abs[sol1], PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, DataReversed -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotLabel -> "FDM"], 
 DensityPlot[Abs[sol2[u, v]], {u, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, ColorFunction -> Hue, Frame -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotLabel -> "NDSolve"]}
```

[image: Figure 5]
Note that solutions look very similar, but nevertheless they have a small difference of $4\times 10^{-3}$

```
{ListPlot[{Table[sol1[[i, i]], {i, n}], 
   Table[sol2[x, x], {x, 0, L, h}]}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> {"FDM", "NDSolve"}], 
 ListPlot[{Table[sol1[[i, i]], {i, n}] - 
    Table[sol2[x, x], {x, 0, L, h}]}, Frame -> True]}
```

[image: Figure 6]

Finally we put `L=400; n=2000` in FDM code and compare FDM solution with `NDSolve` with options

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[eqs, psi, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 2000, "MaxPoints" -> 2000, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];
```

[image: Figure 7]

Comment: You can use `FunctionInterpolation` to rebuild the `Vs` to speed up the calculation :) .

Comment: @Alex Trounev Thank you for your thoughtful answer. From your answer, I learn a lot. And the question will be asked ia that why the initial condition include the `tanh[3 v]`? Secondly, it is quickly to calculate the `Vs`, but the `sol` is too slow.  Can we have a way to make the programe more quick than now it is? At last, except the the method of `Inverse function`, can we have another to calculate the`Vs`? Thank you!

Comment: `Tanh[3 v]` added for consistency of boundary conditions. Actually it is not affected the solution and included to satisfy the `NDSolve` logic only.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, it works.

Comment: @Stone See update to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Thank you for your wonderful report. I tried your algorithms, and they're wonderful and can be worth considering. In fact, of all the methods, it seems that the FDM Method is closest to the problem itself. I think that's why the paper uses FDM instead of other methods. In any case, I would like to thank you for your wonderful remarks. Thank you, I have benefited a lot from this time. Thank you!

Comment: @stone What do you mean by "the FDM Method is closest to the problem itself"?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your solution to this problem. This answer is acceptable to me.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have two questions about your interesting answer.  #1: `rs[r]`  is only valid up to a constant. Why did you choose `rs[0]==2mLog[a^2]`  #2: Which default boundary conditions `p[u,0]==?, p[u,400]==?` are taken by "TensorProductGrid"-method? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Actually I used definition $r_s(r)$ and `bc` from Stone's post.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you. @Stone uses  `p[u,0]==..., p[0,v]==...` I 'm missing  a condition `p[u,400]` to make MethodOfLines work.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please, pay attention on FDM algorithm, that we solve hyperbolic type equation $p_{uv}+Up=0$ with `bc` on `u=0` and `v=0`.  Method of line is not so differ in implementation. But if we call in thi last solution  `val = sol2["ValuesOnGrid"]; dim = Dimensions[val]`, we have out `{494, 2000}` it is why last picture with `NDSolve` not so clear as we get with FDM.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Again Thank you for your effort. Perhaps my question is more basic. Examples of "MethodOfLines"  usually need two boundary conditions concerning the spatial coordinate `v` (see answer @xzczd which also uses two bc). Your answer only uses one condition `p[u,0]` and seems to work too.  That's the point I don't understand.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann “Examples of "MethodOfLines" usually need two boundary conditions concerning the spatial coordinate `v`” No… *usually* the number of b.c. is equal to the order of derivative in corresponding direction. Notice I'm not solving the same PDE as Alex. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450367/58219

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, I got it!

Answer (score 10):

## `NDSolve`-based Solution

```
tend = 500;
lb = -150; rb = -lb;
m = 1/2;
a = 1.01;
rs[r_] = Integrate[1/(1 - (2*m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]), r];
l = 1;
V[r_] = (1 - (2 m)/Sqrt[r^2 + a^2]) (l (l + 1)/(r^2 + a^2));
Vs[r_] = V@InverseFunction[rs][r];
interVs = FunctionInterpolation[Vs[r], {r, lb, rb}]

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

abc = D[u[t, x], x] + direction D[u[t, x], t] == 
    0 /. {{x -> lb, direction -> -1}, {x -> rb, direction -> 1}};

With[{Vs = interVs}, 
 sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] + Vs[x]*u[t, x] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
      u[0, x] == E^(-((x - 10)^2)/18), Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, abc}, 
     u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, lb, rb}, Method -> mol[200, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming]
(* {5.27039, Null} *)

LogPlot[sol[t, 10] // Abs, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityPlot[sol[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Remark

1. Since the wave equation is solved in infinte space, I've set 1st order [absorbing boundary condition (ABC)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128524/1871) to relief reflection of the wave at the boundary. As shown in 2nd picture, though reflections still exist, it's not that large.
2. Further check shows that, even with naive Dirichlet boundary condition, `sol[t, 10] // Abs` remains almost the same at least for $t\in[0,500]$, $x\in[-150,150]$.
3. I've used `FunctionInterpolation` to rebuild `Vs` to avoid the inefficient `InverseFunction`.
4. The obtained solution isn't exactly the same as the one in the question, but the specific value of $r_*$ for FIG. 3 doesn't seem to be given in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11823.pdf). Also, the initial conditions for FIG. 3 aren't explicitly given in the paper either, so I'd like to stop here. Anyway, adjustions of spatial grid size, etc. show the solution above is probably reliable.

---

## Quick Fix for the FDM Code of OP

As shown in the answers of Alex and mine, `NDSolve` is capable of handling the problem, but anyway, let me fix OP's FDM code. At least 4 issues here:

1. The most fatal one: Definition of `coords` is incorrect. The grids on $u=0$, $v=0$ are not covered.
2. The order of difference scheme you chose is $1+1$, which is rather low. (Notice the scheme in the paper is a $2+2$ order scheme. ) Since I'm aiming at a quick fix, I'll leave it alone and simply set a dense enough grid, but do notice if good performance is required, a better scheme is needed.
3. `NSolve` isn't bad, but for large linear system, `LinearSolve` is better.
4. Defintion of `vars` doesn't need to be that complicated.

```
Clear[h]
disc = Simplify[
  Solve[Normal[{p[u + h, v + h] == p[u + h, v + h] + O[h]^3, 
     p[u + h, v] == p[u + h, v] + O[h]^3, p[u, v + h] == p[u, v + h] + O[h]^3}], {D[
     p[u, v], u, v]}, {D[p[u, v], u], D[p[u, v], v]}]]

uend = 500/Sqrt[2];
vend = 500/Sqrt[2];
interVs2 = FunctionInterpolation[Vs[r], {r, -uend, uend}];

equForm = 4*D[p[u, v], u, v] + interVs2[(v - u)/2] p[u, v] == 0 /. disc[[1]]

h = 1/4;
ecu[{u_, v_}] = equForm;

p[0, v_] = N@Exp[-(v - 10)^2/(2*3*3)];
p[u_, 0] = 0.;

coords = Flatten[Table[{u, v}, {u, 0, uend - h, h}, {v, 0, vend - h, h}], 
    1]; // AbsoluteTiming

ecus = ecu /@ coords; // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

vars = p @@@ ({h, h} + # & /@ coords); // AbsoluteTiming

{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[ecus, vars]; // AbsoluteTiming

sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -barray]; // AbsoluteTiming

solmat = Partition[sollst, uend/h // Round];

ArrayPlot[solmat, PlotRange -> All, DataReversed -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solfunc = ListInterpolation[solmat, {{h, uend}, {h, vend}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

With[{r = 37}, 
 LogPlot[solfunc[t - r, t + r] // Abs, {t, r + h, 500/Sqrt[2] - r}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice `h = 1/4` may still be too coarse, but limited by the RAM of my laptop, I can't test further.

Comment: It is a nice code (+1).  Have you FDM code as well?

Comment: @alex I just fixed OP's code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then we can try to improve this code.

Comment: @xzczd  It is very difficult to imagine that this problem will be solved in this way. Thank you for your help. I tried your code. After using interpolation, the speed of the program does become faster. However, in testing, I found that there is an error between the interpolated and unpolluted values. This error may differ in the presentation of the result. So, what do you think of this interpolation?
`Plot[{Va[x], Vs[x]}, {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Stone  “I found that there is an error between the interpolated and unpolluted values. This error may differ in the presentation of the result” Add `MaxRecursion -> 8` to definition of `Va` will make the discrepency negligible. Even with the original `Va`, I don't think the solution will be significantly influenced.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, this way works. There may be some impact. The peak change of the potential function may cause a change in frequency. Deeper content also requires in-depth study of this content. Therefore, we still try to ensure its accuracy as much as possible. Thank you for the plan.