# How to output data according to specific requirements and improve the calculation accuracy of NDsolveValue

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, output-formatting, data

How to output data after solving an equation? That is, the output x, and the y value corresponding to x.

```
ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

In addition, is there any way to improve the calculation accuracy of NDsolveValue? I want the higher the accuracy, the better.

Comment: @xzczd   Your answer in this link (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261065/numerical-solutions-of-active-1d-wave-equations(Section Quick Fix for the FDM Code of OP)) , I found that the result of h=1/4 or 1/6 is the same, and the result is always larger than the real value. Do you know what caused this?

Comment: When you talk about accuracy, is it possible that you mean more significant digits?

Comment: By default `NDSolveValue` will use machine precision calculations. To use arbitrary-precision, specify a `WorkingPrecision`, i.e., add the option `WorkingPrecision -> 20` where the `20` is set to whatever required precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, 30}]

xdata = Table[xx, {xx, 0, 30}];
ydata = Table[ysol /. x -> xx, {xx, 0, 30}];

output = Transpose[{xdata, ydata}];

output // TableForm
```

> [image: table]

Edit: to output the data you can save the notebook to some path. The following will create a file in that path.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Export["myFile.mx", Transpose[{xdata, ydata}]]
```

and then you can import

```
Import["myFile.mx"]
```

Edit: pertaining to [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {x, 0, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```

And now you can check the value of the function at $x=30$ for example -it works in the same way for the other values

```
ysol[x] /. x -> 30
```

> [image: wp]

Comment: If I want to output to a file, what should I do?

Comment: @sfks please have a look at the edit :) Is this what you wanted?

Comment: The result is not two columns. I want two columns without brackets.

Comment: @sfks if you could spend some time to check `Import["myFile.mx"] // Dimensions` you would have seen that the result has two columns. Are you familiar with `Parts` and the `Mathematica` documentation? If not you can find more information online in the docs. I am saying this, because your request is very obscure. You said that you wanted the `x` and the corresponding `y` values. I did that for you and now you say you don't want that. I am confused

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me solve the problem of data output.

Comment: @sfks glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: @sfks I added another edit showing you how you can obtain more significant digits in your result. Can you have a look and let me know if that's what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you  very much!

Comment: @sfks Glad I was able to help. If you found this answer helpful, you might want to consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it