# Solving a Fokker-Planck equation NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want to solve the following Fokker-Planck equation:

$$\partial_t p = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}\left[\varepsilon^2p\right] + \frac{1}{2}\partial_{yy}\left[\varepsilon^2p\right] - \partial_x\left[(9x-x^3)p\right] - \partial_y\left[-yp \right]$$

where $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. The initial condition is a Dirac delta function at the origin.

The code I have so far is

```
delt[x_, y_] := 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{.0015, 0}, {0, .0015}}], {x, 
    y}];
MvFP = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, y, 
     t]\)\) == .5*\[Epsilon]^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(p[x, y, 
       t]\)\) + .5*\[Epsilon]^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((\((9*x - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)])\)*p[x, y, t])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((y*p[x, y, t])\)\);
\[Epsilon] = .2;
sol = NDSolveValue[
   {MvFP,
    p[x, y, 0] == delt[x, y],
    p[-5, y, t] == 0,
    p[5, y, t] == 0,
    p[x, -5, t] == 0,
    p[x, 5, t] == 0
    },
   p, {t, 0, 1}, {y, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}
   ];

Manipulate[Plot3D[
  sol[x, y, t], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  ],
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```

The resulting plot makes little sense. If I put the boundary at $x\in (-1,1)$ and $y \in (-1,1)$, the plot of the solution makes sense, but I would like to be able to visualize the solution over a larger region.

I suspect the issues have something to do with the options for the "Method" of NDSolveValue, but after seeing some other posts, I don't have any good ideas how to pick appropriate options.

Comment: There is also an example on how to solve the [Fokker-Plank equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737) in the documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rule of thumb: if `NDSolve` doesn't work well on solving PDE, and you're sure you haven't made any simple mistake, then usually the problem lies in spatial discretization. When `TensorProductGrid` is chosen for spatial discretization, *usually* we adjust `MinPoints` and `MaxPoints` sub-option, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/196898/1871) is an example. When `FiniteElement` is chosen for spatial discretization, *usually* we adjust `MaxCellMeasure` sub-option.

```
molfem[measure_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};

sol = NDSolveValue[
       {MvFP,
         p[x, y, 0] == delt[x, y], DirichletCondition[p[x, y, t] == 0, True]
         },
       p, {t, 0, 1}, {y, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}, Method -> molfem[0.01]
       ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.31252, Null} *)
```

[image]

`molfem` is a function I keep in my `SystemOpen@"init.m"` file because adjustion of `MaxCellMeasure` option is so frequently needed when playing with `NDSolve`. `DirichletCondition[p[x, y, t] == 0, True]` is equivalent to your original b.c.s but conciser.