# Efficiently defining a SparseArray function

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I've got a fairly large `SparseMatrix` (~60,000 entries in a ~10,000-by-10,000 matrix) that depends on two parameters (`im1` and `im2`).  It's made from eight parts and is mostly banded, plus a top row.

Right now, I make it like this:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total];

r1 = r2 = 1;
e = 0.1;
k1 = k2 = 50;
α12 = 0.5; α21 = 0.5;
m1 = m2 = 0.01;
n1max = 2 k1; n2max = 2 k2;

TM[im1_, im2_] := SparseArray[Join[
  Flatten[Table[
    {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} ->
    - r1 n1 - im1 - (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1 
    - r2 n2 - im2 - (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2 - e
  , {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
  Flatten[Table[
    {2 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r1 n1 + im1
  , {n1, 0, n1max - 1}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
  Flatten[Table[
    {n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1 + m1 n1
  , {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
  Flatten[Table[
    {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r2 n2 + im2
  , {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max - 1}]],
  Flatten[Table[
    {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (-1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2 + m2 n2
  , {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 1, n2max}]],
  Table[
    {1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> -e
  , {n2, 1, n2max}],
  Flatten[Table[
    {1, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> e
  , {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
  Table[
    {1, 1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> e
  , {n2, 1, n2max}]
  ], {(n1max + 1) (n2max + 1), (n1max + 1) (n2max + 1)}, 0.];
```

Sorry that it's a bit complicated but a more minimal example might not have the same performance tuning available.

I'll need to get a particular eigenvector of `TM[im1, im2]` for a number of `{im1, im2}` parameter values.  Looking at timings, I see that setting up the matrix is 3X slower than finding the eigenvector:

```
RepeatedTiming[tm = TM[1., 2.];]
(* {0.32, Null} *)
RepeatedTiming[Eigenvectors[tm, -1, Method -> "Arnoldi"][[1]];]
(* {0.10, Null} *)
```

So, does anyone have ideas on how to speed up constructing `TM`?

I've had a look at @HenrikSchumacher's Q&A [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175327/fast-way-to-reassemble-sparsearrays) but couldn't figure out if it was relevant to my problem or how to adapt it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The way the code is written, you can neither exploit packed arrays nor any vectorization. There are two major reasons:

- Using `Rule` prevents using packed arrays since `Rule` enforces symbolic computations. It is more efficient to feed `SparseArray` with `pat -> vals`, where `pat` is a packed array of dimensions `{nnz, 2}` of integers and `vals` is a packed array of size `{nnz}` (`nnz` is the number of rules).
- Using `Table`s; it is faster than filling arrays with `Do` or `For` loops but not as fast as using vectorized constructs such as `Range`, `ConstantArray`, or `KroneckerProduct`. When things become too complicated to be sorted out by `KroneckerProduct`, just compile the body of the `Table` into a `CompiledFunction`.

Just taking your code for specific values of `im1`, and `im2`. Let's see the timings.

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total];

r1 = r2 = 1.;
e = 0.1;
k1 = k2 = 50;
α12 = 0.5; α21 = 0.5;
m1 = m2 = 0.01;
n1max = 2 k1; n2max = 2 k2;
im1 = 10;
im2 = 10;
rules = Join[ 
     Flatten[Table[{1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> -r1 n1 - im1 - (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1 - r2 n2 - im2 - (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2 - e, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Flatten[Table[{2 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r1 n1 + im1, {n1, 0, n1max - 1}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Flatten[Table[{n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1, {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Flatten[Table[{1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> r2 n2 + im2, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max - 1}]], 
     Flatten[Table[{1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (-1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 1, n2max}]],
     Table[{1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> -e, {n2, 1, n2max}], 
     Flatten[Table[{1, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> e, {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Table[{1, 1 + (n1max + 1) n2} -> e, {n2, 1, n2max}]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
vals0 = Join[
     Flatten[Table[-r1 n1 - im1 - (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1 - r2 n2 - im2 - (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2 - e, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
     Flatten[Table[r1 n1 + im1, {n1, 0, n1max - 1}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Flatten[Table[(r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1, {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]], 
     Flatten[Table[r2 n2 + im2, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max - 1}]], 
     Flatten[Table[(r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2, {n1, 0, n1max}, {n2, 1, n2max}]],
     Table[-e, {n2, 1, n2max}],
     Flatten[Table[e, {n1, 1, n1max}, {n2, 0, n2max}]],
     Table[e, {n2, 1, n2max} ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
A0 = SparseArray[
     rules, {(n1max + 1) (n2max + 1), (n1max + 1) (n2max + 1)}, 0.]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.192017
>
> 0.101042
>
> 0.085255

Okay, here is

I optimized the creation of `vals` and `pat` only really crudely. There might be a good deal of more optimization available, in particular with more background info. (For example, you seem to do certain computations on a rectangular grid... Is there some geometry involved?)

First, a few compiled functions:

```
cf1 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = -r1 n1 - (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1 - r2 n2 - (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2 - e},
    Compile[{{n1, _Real}, {n2, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cf2 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = (r1 n1 (n1 + α12 n2)/k1) + m1 n1},
    Compile[{{n1, _Real}, {n2, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cf3 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = (r2 n2 (α21 n1 + n2)/k2) + m2 n2},
    Compile[{{n1, _Real}, {n2, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg1 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2}},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg2 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = {2 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2}},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg3 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = {n1 + (n1max + 1) n2, 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2}},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg4 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2}},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg5 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = {1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) (-1 + n2), 1 + n1 + (n1max + 1) n2}},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];

cg6 = Block[{n1, n2},
   With[{code = n1max},
    Compile[{{n1, _Integer}, {n2, _Integer, 1}},
     {0 n2 + 1, 1 + n1 + (code + 1) n2},
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
     Parallelization -> True
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Here the new timings:

```
n1range = Range[0., n1max];
n2range = Range[0., n2max];

pat = Join[
     Flatten[Transpose[cg1[n1range, n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     Flatten[Transpose[cg2[Most@n1range, n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     Flatten[Transpose[cg3[Rest@n1range, n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     Flatten[Transpose[cg4[n1range, Most@n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     Flatten[Transpose[cg5[n1range, Rest@n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     KroneckerProduct[(Rest@n2range), (n1max + 1) {1, 1}] + 1,
     Flatten[Transpose[cg6[Rest@n1range, n2range], {1, 3, 2}], 1],
     Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, n2max], Range[1 + (n1max + 1), 1 + (n1max + 1) n2max, (n1max + 1)]}]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First


vals = Join[
     Flatten[cf1[n1range, n2range] - im1 - im2],
     Flatten[KroneckerProduct[r1 Most[n1range] + im1, ConstantArray[1., 1 + n2max]]],
     Flatten[cf2[Rest@n1range, n2range]],
     Flatten[ConstantArray[r2 Most[n2range] + im2, n1max + 1]],
     Flatten[cf3[n1range, Rest@n2range]],
     ConstantArray[-e, n2max],
     ConstantArray[e, n2max (n2max + 1)],
     ConstantArray[e, n2max]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
A = SparseArray[
     pat -> vals, {(n1max + 1) (n2max + 1), (n1max + 1) (n2max + 1)}, 
     0.]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
A == A0
```

> 0.002733
>
> 0.001045
>
> 0.006115
>
> True

You see:

- The actual assembly (the call to `SparseArray`) became 10 times faster.
- The generation of `vals` becomes 100 times faster.
- Overall, the code is about 30 times faster.

Comment: Thanks!  This is just the kind of thing I'd never come up with myself.

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Comment: These all look like points that never get mentioned in the SparseArray Help. +1.