# How to reduce the number of polygons of 3D plots?

Tags: graphics3d

Is it possible to reduce the number of polygons a 3D plot is composed of in Mathematica?

I created this animated inverted gyroid but if I want to make something more complicated it is too large (or it takes too much time) in .wrl .obj. or .stl format (like 200MB or more) to export the 3D plots as frames to Blender, C4D or any other ray tracing software.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6FFRtE7PH34&app=m&persist_app=1

Comment: Hard to say without a concrete example. Try to play with the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options. Probably, you want to set `MaxRecursion -> 0` to get maximal control over the meshing. Moreover, applying `DiscretizeGraphics` may help. In particular, it should convert the plot to a triangle mesh and strips aways the vertex normals and face-wise style information.

Comment: If the surface has the same list of face indices in all frames, it should also possible to export the vertex coordinates (and possibly also the vertex normals) frame-wise and the faces indices (and possibly texture coordinates) only once. But I don't know a data format for that.

Comment: If the vertex coordinates follow a smooth movement, one may think also about spline interpolation in time. This would reduce the number of  key frames to be stored at the cost of some additional but negligible computation for the raytracer when interpolating the key frames. I can image how this could be done with POVray, but is would need some additional programming work.

Comment: All in all, the OBJ-export filter in Mathematica is pretty inefficient. =/

Comment: May be this answer will help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/1089

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried both PlotPoints and MaxRecursion. DiscretizeGraphics is a good idea.

Comment: Could you provide the code that makes your inverted gyroid?