# How to make the ListContourPlot3D smooth and closed?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, data, smoothing

I am struggling with making my plot in ListContourPlot3D smooth and closed. I have seen so many posts regarding the same issue but in other functions, the solution of which can not be applied to ListContourPlot3D.

I have the following data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pfgejjgjmav2cu/H1Data.csv?dl=0

I am using the following command

```
ListContourPlot3D[H1Data, Mesh -> None, Contours -> {0.01}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 25}, {0, 25}}, ContourStyle -> {Blue}]
```

The first issue, as I mentioned is that the plot is not smooth and has a rough surface

[image: The rough surface of the plot]

The second issue concerns closing the surface. If I see the back of the plot it is just like a shell. I would like to make it a closed surface.

[image: The surface with open back]

I just need to have a smooth closed surface with a constant color (as shown), so it doesn't matter if another function can do the job for me.

Answer (score 4):

We can get better sampling by setting [`MaxPlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) to a relatively large value:

```
plot = ListContourPlot3D[H1Data, Mesh -> None, Contours -> {0.01}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 25}, {0, 25}}, ContourStyle -> {Blue}, MaxPlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

To smooth this plot, we can apply @HenrikSchumacher's `GraphDiffusionFlow` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/4346). I'll work on both components separately to use different parameters.

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
c1 = First[ConnectedMeshComponents[mr]];
smooth1 = GraphDiffusionFlow[c1, 40, 0.125, .8]
```

[image]

To retain the hard boundary edge in the small part, I'll close it up with [`ConvexHullMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html).

```
c2 = Last[ConnectedMeshComponents[mr]];
c2 = RegionBoundary[TriangulateMesh[ConvexHullMesh[MeshCoordinates[c2]]]];
smooth2 = GraphDiffusionFlow[c2, 5, 0.125, 1]
```

[image]

Finally, a simple call to [`RepairMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepairMesh.html) will close up the remaining hole. I will take a longer route though in order to apply smooth shading while avoiding hard edges. Essentially I'll render the model and hole patch separately.

```
hole = FindMeshDefects[smooth1, "HoleEdges", "Cell"]["HoleEdges"][[1, 1, 1]];
coords = MeshCoordinates[smooth1];
newcoords = ReplacePart[coords, Thread[hole -> Transpose[{0, 1, 1} Transpose[coords[[hole]]]]]];

Show[
  MeshRegion[newcoords, MeshCells[smooth1, 2], PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading", BaseStyle -> ColorData[112, 2]],
  MeshRegion[newcoords, Polygon[Most[hole]], MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}, BaseStyle -> ColorData[112, 2]],
  MeshRegion[smooth2, PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading", BaseStyle -> ColorData[112, 2]],
  Axes -> True,
  Boxed -> True,
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 25}, {0, 25}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: A very nice and sophisticated answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one question remains. As you can ses, there is a very small blue piece on the upper part of the ListContourPlot3D, which after using the function DiscretizeGraphics vanishes. Is it possible to keep that piece?

Comment: Is it possible also to change the color of the final plot?

Comment: Ah, I thought that small part was noise and removed it with `ConnectedMeshComponents`. I've fixed this and added color in my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer

Comment: However, for me RegionalBoundary gives ""\!\(TriangulateMesh[ConvexHullMesh["code"] is not a correctly specified region""

Comment: What version are you using? Does `RegionQ[mr]` return `True`?

Comment: Yes, it does. My Mathematica version is 11.3.

Comment: I had a typo in my solution. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for your time and consideration.