# How to smooth a ParametricPlot3D surface?

Tags: plotting

How does one smooth a surface produced by a ParametricPlot3D? Basically make corners more rounded, etc. A 3D surface equivalent of applying a gaussian filter to an image.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/4999